# How can I get distinct records from many to many relationship using Linq to Sql

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

For brevity, let's say I have the following 3 tables (m:n): Articles, Topics and a joining table ArticleTopic.  I need to get the top *n* articles for *n* topics.  Each article should only show once for the **entire** result set.

**Article:**
-Id
-Title

**Topic:**
-Id
-Name

**ArticleTopic:**
-Id
-ArticleId
-TopicId

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So if your first article has topics A, B, and C and your second article has topics C, D, E, and F, you want your second article to only show topics D, E, and F because your first article already used topic C?

Comment: Just want to show 3 distinct articles for 2 different topics.

Answer (score 1):

```
topics
   .SelectMany(topic => topic.ArticleTopic)
   .Select(articleTopic => article)
   .Distinct()
```

But it is not obvious to me what you mean by *top n* - I can not see any ranking information in your question.

Comment: There is another 1:n table called ArticleRating that has a FK of ArticleId and Score.  

For example, I need the top 3 highest ranked articles for 3 topics but the article should only appear once for not only each topic, but for the entire result set.

Comment: The highest rated articles over all topics? Then there might be no article for some topics. The top rated article for each topic? In this case how do you select which topic "is done" if you encounter the same top rated article in more then one topic?

Comment: And what about degenerated cases like three topics T1, T2, T3 with the same two articles A1 and A2 each? Return only two articles deviating from the one article per topic rule or return one article twice deviating from the every article only once rule?

Comment: If I'm following you, it won't matter which topic "wins" so to speak. It should be the highest rated article over all topics.  If articles A1 and A2 are showing under T1 (and they also belong to T2), then T2 should have the 3rd top article for that topic.

Comment: Now I got it ... i slightly misunderstood your question. You want to select the top m articles of each of the n topics. But not exactly - if an article belongs to multiple topics you want to select it only once and pick a lower rated article for the other topic(s), right?

Comment: Assume T1 with X, Z and A; T2 with Y, Z and B. Take top two of both topics. X for T1, Y for T2 and Z for one of both. How to decide between taking A or B? The highest rated one?

Comment: If one takes the highest rated, is it then okay to select more than m articles for some topics? T3 with P, Q and A. Picking A will select the third article from T3.

Comment: Exactly right.  Highest rated should dictate whether A or B is selected.  It should be fine to select more than m articles as I can see the issue if not.  Thanks for hanging with me on this.  I've tried several approaches, but nothing I'm satisfied with.